# Polymer: reset paper-input to empty properly without triggering validation

Tags: html, validation, dom, polymer

I'm back on web technologies with Polymer, and feel a bit perplexed considering the way I reset a [paper-input](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input) element.

When i reopend my form, I don't want this:

[image]

But this:

[image]

What i have works properly, I just ask for confirmation of my implementation and request for best practices if it's not the best way to do it.

### Context

- I have a paper-input with automatic validation, which value is **required**.
- I want to use it several times in the application life-time.
- I use it in a custom element.
- I use data-binding to feed my back-end with the user input, when he clicks on a 'save' button which is also part of the same custom element.
- We can open and close this element.

### Use case

- I type into my input-paper
- click the button, the element hides and my data are properly saved as expected
- I reopen my element (just becomes visible), and perform the following:

  - I *disable* the autovalidation of the input field not to have the error message as this field is *required* and **then cannot be empty**
  - my paper-input value is reset to an empty string
  - I *enable* the autovalidation
- And so on

### My question

When I reset the `paper-input` value with the empty string I avoid the auto-validation to display the error message "Need some text!" by using an intermediary property called `muteValidation` that is bound to the attribute `auto-validate`:

**DOM:**

```
  <paper-input
      label="Type your word"
      always-float-label
      placeholder="English"
      required
      auto-validate$="[[muteValidation]]"
      error-message="Needs some text!"
      value="{{word.english}}">
  </paper-input>
```

**Script:**

```
  open: function() {
    this._setOpened(true);
    this.create();
  },

  create: function() {
    this._setOpened(true);
    this.muteValidation = false;
    this.set('word.english', '');
    this.muteValidation = true;
    Polymer.dom(this).classList.add('open');
  },
```

To me it sounds kinda weird to use a property `muteValidation` just to do a simple reset of my field.
Is my code right or completely evil?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem of form validating on load with empty values. How did you solved this ?

Comment: For me it was just fine to disable the auto validation (see the code above around _muteValidation_) by default and then re-enable it.
Got it to work like that, but I don't find it really elegant...

Comment: Ah I have plenty of elements on my page :(

Comment: The `muteValidation` property can be shared between all of this, it will still make your markup heavier as you will have to spread the attribute binding `auto-validate$="[[muteValidation]]"` ; but not the script.
Not really the choice with my work around... If you find any better way please let me know!